# ApiGatewayMethod<lambda-name>Options - Invalid Resource identifier specified

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway, serverless, aws-serverless

My serverless.yml looks like below, it is already deployed, but when I try deploy again to make some changes, I get this error `An error occurred: ApiGatewayMethod<lambda-name>Options - Invalid Resource identifier specified (Service: AmazonApiGateway; Status Code: 404; Error Code: NotFoundException`

Serverless framework version: 2.21.1

```
service:
    name: meetup-registration-apis
custom:
    webpack:
        webpackConfig: ./webpack.config.js
        includeModules: true
plugins:
    - serverless-dotenv-plugin
    - serverless-offline
    - serverless-webpack

provider:
    name: aws
    runtime: nodejs14.x
    apiGateway:
        minimumCompressionSize: 1024 # Enable gzip compression for responses > 1 KB
    environment:
        AWS_NODEJS_CONNECTION_REUSE_ENABLED: 1
        STORAGE_BUCKET: ${env:S_STORAGE}
    iamRoleStatements:
        - Effect: Allow
          Action:
              - dynamodb:DescribeTable
              - dynamodb:Query
              - dynamodb:Scan
              - dynamodb:GetItem
              - dynamodb:PutItem
              - dynamodb:UpdateItem
              - dynamodb:DeleteItem
          Resource: *
functions:
    registerAttendee:
        handler: src/handler.registerAttendee
        events:
            - http:
                  method: post
                  path: registerAttendee
                  cors: true
    getAttendees:
        handler: src/handler.getAttendees
        events:
            - http:
                  method: get
                  path: getAttendees
                  cors: true
```

Not sure where I'm going wrong. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Try to review the failed template as transformed and see if there is anything you can debug from that....

Answer (score 1):

Could you consider upgrading your version of the serverless framework? Version 2.21.1 is over a year old and using the latest version ([v3.7.5](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serverless) as of March 16, 2022), I was able to deploy the stack as well as make changes without any issues.

However, I had to make the following updates to the template in order to make it compatible with v3:

- Changed the service definition to `service: meetup-registration-apis`, as object notations for the service property were deprecated starting with [v3.0.0](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/deprecations)
- Put the asterisk inside the IAM statement into quotation marks (`Resource: '*'`)
- Replaced the serverless-dotenv-plugin with the `useDotenv: true` setting, which was introduced in [v3.0.0](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/environment-variables/). This is optional, but v3 introduced some [changes](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serverless-dotenv-plugin) that significantly impacted this plugin.

If updating is not an option, could you please add what changes you are trying to make to the already deployed stack (how does the template look like before/after)?

Comment: removing the complete cloudformation stack and re-deploying it worked for me. However, switching to the latest serverless version is definitely a good idea, I'll try that. Thanks for the all the suggestions.